# Git diff between local repo and origin repo

Tags: git

If I run these commands:

```
On branch dev
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
me:cdt-now me$ git diff
me:cdt-now me$
```

so there is no diff - is that because I need to do

```
git diff origin/dev
```

?

I would have thought that git diff would default to

```
git diff origin/dev
```

but maybe not.

Comment: git diff dev origin/dev. You need to provide your local path and origin.

Comment: why `git diff dev origin/dev`? I think if you are on the dev branch already then `git diff origin/dev` should be sufficient, but I guess your answer is clearer because it's all there in the command.

Comment: If you run `git diff` with no arguments at all, it compares the current contents of the index to the current contents of the work-tree. No branch names enter the picture anywhere, nor does the current commit. In other words, except for showing actual *changes* (instead of just file names), this is like the second of the two diffs that `git status` runs for you. (To get the first of those two diffs, run `git diff --cached` with no arguments.)

Answer (score 2):

By default `git diff` will look at your current branch and see if there are any differences. So if you made some changes on your current branch that are unstaged, a `git diff` would show those differences. Once you've staged changed (`git add .`), you won't see them unless you specify `git diff --cached`.

In regards to the behavior of `git diff` for branches, when you specify another branch, yes it should diff against it. By default if you have simply branched off of a remote branch, git diff and then specifying a branch should diff your current branch (index is the more appropriate term) and diff against the branch you specify. However, be aware that your `origin/dev` is your local representation of the remote branch and you need to make sure that is updated via `git fetch`.

Also in your case, it looks like you committed your change. A `git diff` against a branch should show the difference but if this is your local branch and you simply want to see the diff of your last commit again, remember you can also specify `HEAD` references and go back X number of commits. So to go and see the diff of your last commit, you can do `git diff HEAD~1`

More info on [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).